# How to profile L1 and L2 cache hit ratios on GTX480 using cuda 4.2 profiler on Linux?

Tags: performance, cuda, gpu, gpgpu

I used one previous version of Nvidia profiler to profile l1 and l2 cache hit ratios, but I'm not sure which version I used. It seems cuda 4.2 visual profiler doesn't have L1 and L2 profiling information(except global cache replay overhead). How can I profile L1 or L2 cache hit ratios using cuda 4.2(or a specific previous version) visual/command-line profiler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not sure if you are using windows or linux but with windows you have the Parallel Nsight for MS Visual Studio (there is also a version for eclipse). Nsight lets you define many different "experiments". Even you can use "custom" experiments. If you select "memory" experiments, it will include the desired L1 and L2 cache hit ratios. I attach a screenshot showing that[image: Parallel Nsight Performance screenshot]

This is taken from NSight paralell 3.0 but its also available in previous versions.

**EDITED:**

Using visual profiler (at least version 5.0 but I guess previous versions will be similar) you can setup what events and metrics you are interested on, in Visual Profiler 5.0 you can hit Run --> Configure Metrics and Events. In the attached window you can set whatever counter you want to watch. The available metrics and events will depend on the underlying hardware (ie. accessible counters your GPU has). Attach picture for some memory counters in my GTX 480
[image: Cache Events GTX 480 visual profiler 5.0]

**EDITED 2:**
Ok just noticed you are asking for Linux after editing the original question ... so for linux I don't know if NVidia provides such a Visual Profiler (I guess they do). If not, you may be interested in Eclipse NSight version ...